# how i can use attach function in c++ with mbed

Tags: c++, uart, mbed

i'm actually work on mbed card and i hava to update a code on version 5 of the os to version 6. but i have a probleme with the attach function on Uart class i have no compilation error, no error when i test the code but i never in my getuserinput function. i don't know if in c++ it's possible but i try something i make classe call Uart. if someone know the answer or have a solution it will be great.

**code version 5**

```
 void on_rx_interrupt() {  
        char c;
        if (serial_port.read(&c, 1)) {
            if (c == '/') {
                NVIC_SystemReset();
            } 
        }
    }
 

    int main(void) {
        serial_port.baud(115200);
        serial_port.format(8, SerialBase::None, 1);

        serial_port.attach(&on_rx_interrupt, SerialBase::RxIrq);
    }
```

**New code c++**
*UART class*

```
 void getUserInput() {
        printf("get input\n");
        char c;
    
        while (pc.readable()) {   
            pc.read(&c, 1);
            if (c == '#') {
                 printf("mdr");
            }
        
            if (c == '/') {
                printf("lol");
                NVIC_SystemReset();
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    void Uart::algo() {
        this->initUartPort();

        pc.attach(&getUserInput, SerialBase::RxIrq);
    }
```

*MAIN*

```
int main( int ac, char** av) {
    Uart uart;

    uart.algo();
}
```

thanks for answer

Comment: I have no errors the compilation is perfect I just never fit into this function and I don't understand why

Comment: sorry i'm not very good in english i ment i never enter in getuserinput function